# XMPP component presence

Tags: components, xmpp

I have just discovered how awesome XMPP is and I am experimenting with developing multiplayer games as XMPP components (XEP-0114).

However, I am having trouble with indicating presence for the component. Is it true, that the component will need to respond to <presence> stanzas itself?

Sure it can do that, but not if it is down for maintenance. Also, who does the component notify when it is back up? It could of course register all interested users in a database, but if it is down for five minutes, then that list surely will have changed. Users that were not previously interested will be now, and users who were interested won't be any more.

Also, if it crashes (could happen), it cannot send out 'unavailable' presence indications.

Can't this work somehow be offloaded to the server?

Comment: What programming language?  What XMPP library?

Comment: I use JavaScript with node-xmpp. However this should be protocol, not specific to implementation...unless I have misunderstood something.

Comment: You're correct, except that in certain environments (like SleekXMPP), there is an existing class to handle the protocol for you, which would have been a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

1. When your component receives `<presence type='probe'/>`, it should reply with your component's current presence.
2. When your component receives `<presence type='subscribe'/>`, it should save the `from` address in a some sort of storage mechanism, then reply with `<presence type='subscribed'/>`.
3. When your component comes online, it should send presence to each of the subscribers saved in step 2.

Always make sure to put both a `to` address and a `from` address on all stanzas sent by your component.  If you are used to writing clients, you're likely to forget that in step 3.

Comment: Alright, but what if it takes five minutes for the component to come back online? The list of interested users will surely have changed, so the users recorded in step two will be obsolete.

Comment: No, the list of users recorded in step two does not change unless you get a unsubscribe.  That's the list of people interested in your presence.  You don't care if you send presence to someone not online, or if you send a second copy of presence to someone who has already received it (before you crashed).

Comment: But if a new user comes along and want to register with my component while it is gone it will not receive the presence subscription and the user will not receive a reply. Then when the component does come online it will not know about the new user and the user will not know that the component is now online.

Comment: Some servers will re-send the subscribe for the client whenever it logs in.